# How to convert a character into a boolean two dimensional array in Android?

Tags: java, android, boolean, type-conversion

I'm working on a project that requires converting a character into a two dimensional array in Android. For example, if I have the character (or string) "A", I must create a two dimensional array like this:

```
[0,0,1,0,0]   
[0,1,0,1,0]    
[0,1,0,1,0]    
[1,0,0,0,1]    
[1,1,1,1,1]    
[1,0,0,0,1]    
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Graphically:

[image]

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: My first thought is "table".  Come to think of it, "table" is my second and third thoughts, too :)  Definitely add "homework" tab if applicable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
String str = "ABC";
List<byte[][]> codedString = new ArrayList<byte[][]>();

for ( char c : str.toCharArray() ) {

    switch ( c ) {

        case 'A':
            codedString.add( new byte[][]{
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } } );
            break;

        case 'B':
            codedString.add( new byte[][]{
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 } } );
            break;

        case 'C':
            codedString.add( new byte[][]{
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 } } );
            break;

    }

}

for ( byte[][] codedChar : codedString ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < codedChar.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < codedChar[i].length; j++ ) {
            System.out.print( codedChar[i][j] == 1 ? "X" : " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You will need to hardcode all the patterns.

**Edit:** I changed my code to use zeros and ones to represent the pattern. It is easier to read than using booleans.

Comment: you probably shouldn't have been quite so generous if this were a homework assignment (which it definitely *sounds* like it might be...)

Comment: Thanks! You hit the spot. This will definitively work. Any idea how this can work for an image? Let's say that I have a .jpg or .png file, I need to convert it to a binary array, but not hard coded like you did for characters.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you're are trying to represent each character in a 5x7 pixel grid. One way to do this would be store all characters ('A' to 'Z' & more if if you want) representation in a hard-coded map and return/access them as necessary.